# R shiny Server Pro Implementing Single Sign On

Tags: r, single-sign-on, shiny-server

We have been using Shiny Server with LDAP to authenticate users when they access a shiny app. But what we really want to do is give our users access to a gallery of shiny plots embedded in a webpage behind a login screen.

The problem is... once users login to the gallery page how do we pass their credentials to the shiny apps embedded there? As things stand now if we had three shiny apps embedded with iFrames on one page the users would need to reenter their credentials 3 times in each of the separate iFrame windows.

Is there a way to use a Single Sign On protocol to pass a user authentication to shiny server apps?

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Shiny Server Pro, you could configure it behind a proxy that handles authentication as well.  We do have additional authentication flows planned on our roadmap for Shiny Server Pro in the coming year.